# DataTables 650k muy lento. Server-side funciona?

Tags: laravel, datatables

Actualmente estoy haciendo un filtrado de datos. Cuando hago una consulta de aproximadamente 650k de registros el dataTable tarda mucho en cargar y además me sobrecarga la memoria de la computadora.
A veces me devuelve error 500 del server. Probé la consulta directamente en phpmyadmin y tarda mucho menos. A veces devuelve el siguiente error:

```
DataTables warning: table id = tabla_users Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

**Controller:**

```
                       $data = collect(DB::select("SELECT distinct usuarios.usuario_id, empresas.nombre_empresa as empresa, usuarios.apellido as apellido, usuarios.autorizado, usuarios.dni, usuarios.dni, usuarios.email, usuarios.fecha_creacion, usuarios.habilitado, usuarios.nombre AS nombre, usuarios.origen, usuarios.reportado, usuarios.telefono, team.equipo AS teams, aplicaciones.nombre AS nombre_app
                      FROM usuarios, usuario_aplicacion, aplicaciones, team_usuario, team, empresas, usuarios_empresa
                      WHERE  aplicaciones.aplicacion_id IN ( $aplicaciones )
                      AND usuario_aplicacion.aplicacion_id IN ($aplicaciones)
                      AND usuarios.email = usuarios_empresa.email
                      AND usuarios.email = usuario_aplicacion.email
                      AND usuarios.email = team_usuario.email_usuario
                      AND team_usuario.id_team = team.id_team
                      AND usuarios_empresa.id_empresa = empresas.id_empresa
                      AND team.id_team
                      IN ( $equipos )"));
```

**Ajax desde la vista:**

```
                var tabla = $('#tabla_usuario').DataTable({
                initComplete: function( settings, json ) {
                    $('.cargando').hide();

                },
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                fixedHeader: true,
                orderCellsTop: true,
                lengthMenu: [ 50 ],
                paging: true,
                scrollX: true,
                lengthChange : true,
                searching: true,
                ordering: true,
                bDestroy: true,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel'
                ],
                ajax: {
                    url: "{{ URL::route('route') }}",
                    dataSrc: '',
                    dataType:"json",
                    data: {
                        'fecha_desde': $("#fecha_desde").val(),
                        'fecha_hasta': $("#fecha_hasta").val(),
                        'aplicacion': JSON.stringify(ArrayAplicaciones),
                        'equipos': JSON.stringify(ArrayEquipos)
                    },
                },
                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: 'user' },
                    { data: 'name' },
                    { data: 'lastname' },
                    { data: 'code_id' },
                    { data: 'email' },
                    { data: 'date' },
                    { data: 'tel' },
                    { data: 'aplic' },
                    { data: 'teams' },
                    { data: 'empresa' }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: no sé mucho de php pero he usado datatables js en c#, si no segmentas tu consulta, cada vez que cargue el datatable estarás pidiendo que traiga todos tus registros... lo que yo hice, es que sólo cargue los elementos que se ven en pantalla.

Comment: Como segmentaria los datos ? Como hago que se carguen solo los que se ven en pantalla ?

Comment: Tu query es muy ineficiente, es mejor que utilices JOINs en lugar de hacer los cruces de esa manera